# In what metric spaces does bounded + unique limit point imply convergence of a sequence?

Tags: general-topology, analysis, convergence-divergence, metric-spaces

A theorem stated by multiple sources is that any sequence of real numbers converges if and only if it is bounded and has a unique limit point.  Apostol has a theorem that generalizes half of this: for any sequence in a metric space, convergence implies bounded and a unique limit point.

There are counterexamples to the other half, for instance a sequence in the open interval $(0,2)$ which alternates between 1 and $1/n$: $1,1/2,1,1/3,1,1/4,...$ is clearly bounded, has only the limit point 1 because 0 isn't in the space, but diverges.  There are even counterexamples in complete metric spaces, for instance take the natural numbers (or the reals, if you prefer) with the discrete metric
where $d(x,x)=0$ and $d(x,y)=1$ for $x\neq y$.  The sequence $1,2,1,3,1,4,1,5,...$ has only the limit point 1 but diverges, and under the discrete metric the sequence is actually bounded because all points are within distance 1.

My question is, what condition must be true on the metric space (not on the sequence) in order for bounded + unique limit point to imply convergence?  I expect that if it's true for the reals, it's true in any ${\mathbb R}^n$ (with the usual Euclidean metric), and I expect completeness must be necessary, but it's clearly not sufficient.

Thanks for helping me think about this!

Comment: You just need compactness, no? Though maybe this is a cop out because then bounded is  replaced with totally bounded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is equivalent to a metric space being proper, i.e., closed bounded subsets are compact  (hence both your suspicions were correct, as $\mathbb R^n$ is proper and every proper metric space is complete).

In one direction it's clear, since in a proper metric space, if $\{x_n\}$ is bounded and contains a unique limit point $x$, then $\{x_n\}$ is in some closed bounded set $ B$, which is compact by properness, so every subsequence has a further subsequence which converges (by compactness of $B$) to $x$ (by uniqueness), whereby $x_n$ converges to $x$.

Conversely, if $X$ is not proper, let $B\subseteq X$ be a closed and bounded noncompact subset. Then there is a sequence (necessarily bounded) $\{x_n\}$ in $B$ with no convergent subsequence in $B$, hence none in $X$ at all since $B$ is closed.

Let $x_0\in X$ be arbitrary.

Then the sequence $\{y_n\}$ given by $y_{2k}=x_k$, $y_{2k+1}=x_0$ is bounded and has exactly one limit point, namely $x_0$, yet does not converge to $x_0$.

Comment: This sounds right to me, but there are two points in your proof that I can't follow, where you connect compactness to whether or not subsequences of sequences converge. You write (a) "every subsequence has a further subsequence which converges (by compactness of B) to x (by uniqueness), whereby xn converges to x." I don't follow the "whereby", and would have expected only to conclude from compactness that a subsequence of $\{x_n\}$ converges (though I can see the subsubsequence claim is also true).

Comment: Then (b) "there is a sequence $\{x_n\}$ in B with no convergent subsequence in B." I know compact implies a convergent subsequence, but is it an if-and-only-if?

Comment: @Christopher it’s a known fact that if every subsequence has a further subsequence converging to $x$, then the original sequence converges to $x$.  The proof for that is essentially that if $x_n$ does not converge to $x$, then there is fixed neighborhood $U$ of $x$ that $x_n$ frequently avoids, and therefore a subsequence entirely avoids $U$.  Then no further subsequence could converge to $x$.

Comment: @Christopher as to your second point, compactness in a metric space is equivalent to sequential compactness, ie, every sequence has a convergent subsequence.  The negation of that condition is that there is some sequence with no convergent subsequence.

Comment: Just to clarify, the statement that “if every subsequence has a further subsequence converging to $x$, then the original sequence converges to $x$” does not rely on compactness at all, and follows directly from the definition of convergence.

Comment: Thank you for the additional explanations. That clears it up for me!